# uitableviewcell accessory type not showing in first click

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have the custom UITableViewCell and this code to create the accessory when row click

```
 public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (this.checkedIndexPath != null)
        {
            var uncheckCell = tableView.CellAt(checkedIndexPath) as UITableViewCell;
            if (uncheckCell != null)
            { 
                uncheckCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
            }
        }
        if (tableView.CellAt(indexPath) is UITableViewCell cell)
        {
            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark; 
        }
        this.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
```

I have a problem . When I click on a cell the first time. Type of accessories does not change. When I click on another cell, the accessory type changes. But the accessory type of the second mouse click does not change until I click another cell in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reload the current cell for the changes to take effect

```
tableView.ReloadRows(indexPath, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
```

Add it at the end of your code

```
 public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (this.checkedIndexPath != null)
        {
            var uncheckCell = tableView.CellAt(checkedIndexPath) as UITableViewCell;
            if (uncheckCell != null)
            { 
                uncheckCell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
            }
        }
        if (tableView.CellAt(indexPath) is UITableViewCell cell)
        {
            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark; 
        }
        this.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;

        //Reload current cell
        tableView.ReloadRows(indexPath, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
    }
```